# WPF - MVVM - View model hierarchy

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Can somone give me an example why would I need a ViewModel taht contains two sub View models ? and how do I implement this ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you got a "MainContainer" which is your top-level ViewModel, you might need 2 different sub-viewmodels: One for a "Menu" and one for the content that the menu points to.

It could be implemented like this:

```
public MenuViewModel Menu;
public ContentViewModel Content;
```

You'd bind a container in your main view to each of these viewmodels, and on update insert a view depending on your viewmodel. How you map the viewmodels to the view, can depend, and there's no "pretty" solution. Personally, I like to keep it in my top-view resources, using a datatemplate.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the End-to-end sample on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd238515.aspx). Unfortunately there is no walk-through but I found it instructional, a small but complete app using WPF, MVVM, EF4 and POCOs.